# Deploy Docker Image to Heroku (Error R10)

Tags: python, docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, heroku

I am trying to deploy a docker image to heroku from my docker app.
So basically I build this image locally on my computer: https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome

I ran some tests and it seems to work without problems locally.
Now I wanted to deploy this docker image to heroku.
I followed this official instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

It seems to work but if I check the logs online I end up always with the error:
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

I don't really know what I have to do.
Would be great if you can help me.

Comment: What is the script or YAML configuration you are using to run/deploy the image?

Comment: Locally I can just run it with the docker app. To deploy it on heroku I just followed the instructions of their official page (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). I thought I don't need to specify more configurations. It sounds like it is possible to push existing Images without problems "To push an image to Heroku, such as one pulled from Docker Hub, tag it and push it according to this naming template..."

Comment: Somewhere there should be a port mapping - that's what I'm getting at.